# Helm: howto use ".Files.Get" to import a json into a config map

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I try to import a json file into a configmap but the map doesn't contain the file.

my ConfigMap-Template:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: serilog-configmap
data:
  serilog.json: |-
{{ .Files.Get "serilog.json" | indent 4}}
```

serilog.json is in the root-path of the Project, there is a sub-dir with the Chart and the templetes ( from helm create ).

I allso tried "../../serilog.json" and the fullpath as the filename but it allways ends with the same result when i run helm install --debug --dry-run.

```
---
# Source: hellowebapi/templates/serilogConfigMap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: serilog-configmap
data:
  serilog.json: |-
---
```

I would excpect:

```
---
# Source: hellowebapi/templates/serilogConfigMap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: serilog-configmap
data:
  serilog.json: |-
{
    "Serilog": {
        "Using": [
            "Serilog.Sinks.ColoredConsole"
        ],
...
---
```

Can anybody tell me where i make my mistake?

Answer (score 15):

Try this :

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: serilog-configmap
data:
  serilog.json: |-
    {{- $.Files.Get "configurations/serilog.json"  | nindent 6 -}}
```

with a relative path for the json file (`hellowebapi/configurations/serilog.json`)

It will produce :

```
---
# Source: serilog/templates/test.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: serilog-configmap
data:
  serilog.json: |-
      {
          "apiVersion": "v1",
          "kind": "Pod",
          "metadata": {
              "annotations": {
```

Comment: I think you should use `nindent 4` since your files here have 2 spaces for indentation

Answer (score 1):

Your *json* file should be in your chart directory.

See [Accessing Files Inside Templates](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/accessing_files/)

```
λ ls
Chart.yaml  charts/  serilog.json  templates/  values.yaml

λ helm template .
---
# Source: templates/configmap.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: serilog-configmap
data:
  serilog.json: |-
    {
      "Serilog": {
        "Using": [
            "Serilog.Sinks.ColoredConsole"
        ]
      }
    }
```